In Tab Bar I use label indicator I add Tab Bar indicator border radius how I can give it radius

I add tab bar when I use indicator size as a label I show label indicator topright & topleft curve border
TabBar( 
indicatorColor: mainColor,
 /*indicator: BoxDecoration(
 //borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(5),topRight: Radius.circular(5))
               ),*/
 indicatorWeight: 5,
  indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,`your text`
)


Please share image you want to achieve.

okay i add images please check

Ty to use CustomTabIndicator as below...
Give indicator:CustomTabIndicator()
class CustomTabIndicator extends Decoration {
      final double radius;
      final Color color;
      final double indicatorHeight;
    
      const CustomTabIndicator({
        this.radius = 15,
        this.indicatorHeight = 10,
        this.color = Colors.black,
      });
    
      @override
      _CustomPainter createBoxPainter([VoidCallback? onChanged]) {
        return _CustomPainter(
          this,
          onChanged,
        );
      }
    }
    
    class _CustomPainter extends BoxPainter {
      final CustomTabIndicator decoration;
    
      _CustomPainter(
          this.decoration,
          VoidCallback? onChanged,
          ) : super(onChanged);
    
      @override
      void paint(Canvas canvas, Offset offset, ImageConfiguration configuration) {
        assert(configuration.size != null);
    
        final Paint paint = Paint();
        double xAxisPos = offset.dx + configuration.size!.width/2;
        double yAxisPos = offset.dy + configuration.size!.height - 15/2;
    
        RRect fullRect = RRect.fromRectAndCorners(
          Rect.fromCenter(
            center: Offset(xAxisPos, yAxisPos),
            width: configuration.size!.width ,
            height: 15,
          ),
          topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(15),
        );
    
        canvas.drawRRect(fullRect, paint);
      }
    }


it work but when i change a lable color it not change

Add labelColor: Colors.yellow to TabBar.

labelColor is not work

Refer this image https://ibb.co/TtgKN25 , do you have anything else to do?

how i can change a indicator color?

Add paint.color =Colors.red to  _CustomPainter after double yAxisPos = offset.dy + configuration.size!.height - 15 / 2;
